# Galleria Option carousel:false not working

Tags: javascript, galleria

I have a little problem with the plugin Galleria.

The option carousel:false is not working for me

```
(function() {
    Galleria.loadTheme('./js/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
    Galleria.configure({
        transition: 'fade',
        transitionSpeed: 3000,
        carousel:false
    });
    Galleria.run('.galleria',{
        autoplay: 4000
    });
}());
```

But the carousel is still there

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

`You can also add options as a second argument when calling Galleria.run:`
(http://docs.galleria.io/article/118-using-options)

Which probably means that if you pass options into the `run()` function, it will overwrite the previous options passed into `configure()`

Try this instead:

```
(function() {
    Galleria.loadTheme('./js/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
    Galleria.configure({
        transition: 'fade',
        transitionSpeed: 3000,
        carousel: false,
        autoplay: 4000
    });
    Galleria.run('.galleria');
}());
```